# Convert fonts - TrueType (TTF) to PostScript Type 1 (PT1)

Tags: fonts, truetype

Is there anyway I can convert my ttf fonts to PostScript Type 1 (pt1) format? I tried out this ttf2pt1 tool (http://ttf2pt1.sourceforge.net/) that is mentioned a lot around the Internet, but it doesn't work (can't compile on my server). Last update is from 2003, so no big surprise. So, are there any other ways to convert ttf to pt1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/ should do what you need here.

I'm very curious why you'd need to do this, though? Must be a very old application/framework?

Comment: I am generating PDF's for a printing facility. As the process they file, the split and merge the pages. In that process, they seem to have problems with some of the TTF fonts I use.

Comment: If it is only "some" of the TTFs, then I'd suggest getting those fonts repaired or replaced as there is likely some flaw in them. Converting them to PostScript Type 1 might get them to work for you, but doesn't exactly solve the problem.

Comment: I wrote a little script using FontForge on the command line to convert my ttf files to psb files. The script is based on http://www.stuermer.ch/blog/convert-otf-to-ttf-font-on-ubuntu.html. Once my fonts were converted to psb, it was easy to detect which fonts caused problems when embedded in a PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout https://everythingfonts.com/ttf-to-pt1. It worked for the couple of fonts that I tried. Your mileage may vary.